# Visual Studio "Navigate to" feature on current document only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to limit amazing `Navigate To` (`Ctrl + ,`) feature of Visual Studio to go through current document only?

Basically I am looking for `Go to File Member` of [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html), but in vanilla VS.